# MPU6050 accelerometer giving output as -1 -1. Can anyone tell the issue in the code?

Tags: arduino-uno, accelerometer, mpu6050

```
// MPU-6050 Short Example Sketch
// By Arduino User JohnChi
// August 17, 2014
// Public Domain
#include<Wire.h>
const int MPU_addr=0x68;  // I2C address of the MPU-6050
int16_t AcX,AcY,AcZ,Tmp,GyX,GyY,GyZ;

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire.write(0); // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU_addr,14,true);  // request a total of 14 registers
  AcX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)    
  AcY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
  AcZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)
  Tmp=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x41 (TEMP_OUT_H) & 0x42 (TEMP_OUT_L)
  GyX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) & 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
  GyY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) & 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
  GyZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x47 (GYRO_ZOUT_H) & 0x48 (GYRO_ZOUT_L)
  Serial.print("AcX = "); Serial.print(AcX);
  Serial.print(" | AcY = "); Serial.print(AcY);
  Serial.print(" | AcZ = "); Serial.print(AcZ);
  Serial.print(" | Tmp = "); Serial.print(Tmp/340.00+36.53);  //equation for temperature in degrees C from datasheet
  Serial.print(" | GyX = "); Serial.print(GyX);
  Serial.print(" | GyY = "); Serial.print(GyY);
  Serial.print(" | GyZ = "); Serial.println(GyZ);
  delay(333);
}
```

Serial Monitor output:

```
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
[…]
```

Comment: You need to initialize the device and take it out of sleep mode first.

Comment: A return value of -1 means that the Wire.read is reading an empty buffer. In other words: you are not connected to the mpu6050. Try a i2c scanner first: https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner

Comment: Thanks Jot..! you point out the problem. My MPU was not connected to the arduino. Actually in arduino's MCU i2c module was not working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there was a communication problem between MPU and Arduino which I found using code given in this link http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner .
Then I found thought problem Must be in MPU or arduino and problem was in Arduino MCU.
So after changing the Arduino MCU it worked

Comment: Acept your own answer to close the question